# Screencast on a virtual monitor

Tags: linux, x11, screencasting

Is it possible to create a virtual monitor (virtual area) and cast it to LAN?
I would like to have some type of external monitor, like [Miracast](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2907520/how-to-use-miracast-to-mirror-your-devices-screen-wirelessly-on-your-tv.html), but not a mirror.

I think it is possible to create a virtual area, record it (and compress by h264 or vp8) and share it by e.g. DLNA.
Like this page: *[Live Desktop Streaming via DLNA on GNU/Linux](http://realmike.org/blog/2011/02/09/live-desktop-streaming-via-dlna-on-gnulinux/)*.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Is your aim just to display programs running on your computer on the monitor of another computer, with both computers running Linux? Or are you doing something more exotic?

Comment: @Gilles I want it mainly for watching movies (also flash from Web browser), but mayby normal programs also. If it's possible I want to use some standard like dlna, but I could use Raspberry pi as reciver.

Comment: @Gilles do you know how to "display programs running my computer on the screen of another computer, with both computers running GNU+linux"?? directly?? I definitely want that!